# Truncate content after 2 lines in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforce1-app, lightning-experience

I am trying to show some lines of content in small div ( which i am building for utility bar). Tried so many ways to show the content for first 2 lines and rest show as .... Also tried using slds-truncate class which will truncate everything in 1st line. But I need to show the content for 2 or 3 lines and later the excessive details should be trucated ( show ... symbols). please suggest.

```
<div style="height: 420px;overflow-y: hidden;">
<lightning:layout>            
    <div class="slds-container_medium searchContentCls" title="On Hover">
        <div class="slds-p-top_large slds-p-left_small slds-p-right_small slds-border_bottom">
            <div class="slds-wrap">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="-1">
                    Super long header string comeing from apex - I am testing the length of it.
                </a>
            </div><br/>
            <div class="slds-wrap">
                <span style="white-space: nowrap; width: 100px;  overflow: hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;">
                    This is a area where we are going to display the content returned from the webservice. This is a area where we are going to display the content returned from the webservice.
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>                
    </div>
</lightning:layout>
```

Used Span, Div, P and anchor tag. But no luck. Has anyone faced the same issue ? The result is coming as shown in the pic.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to use SLDS class **"slds-truncate"**

```
<div style="height: 420px;overflow-y: hidden;">
<lightning:layout>            
    <div class="slds-container_medium searchContentCls" title="On Hover">
        <div class="slds-p-top_large slds-p-left_small slds-p-right_small slds-border_bottom">
            <div class="slds-wrap">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="-1">
                    Super long header string comeing from apex - I am testing the length of it.
                </a>
            </div><br/>
            <div class="slds-wrap">
                <span style="white-space: nowrap; width: 100px;  overflow: hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;">
                    <p class="slds-truncate" >This is a area where we are going to display the content returned from the webservice. This is a area where we are going to display the content returned from the webservice.</p>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>                
    </div>
</lightning:layout>
    </div>
```

[image]

Src: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/truncation/

Comment: I did use the slds-truncate also. But It is truncating the result at the end of 1st line itself. I was trying to take the content upto 2 lines and then truncate. My bad I should have mentioned about the "slds-truncate" in the initial post. @Pranay